# CSS/SCSS rgb colors with MDL

Tags: css, sass, gulp-sass, material-design-lite

I'm using the Material Design Lite library, included in my project via bower so I can build a custom version with only modules I need.

However, when it comes to colors something weird is happening that I can't work out.

In the compiled css the colors are being defined as..

```
.mdl-button--accent.mdl-button--accent {
  color: rgb(#f2545b);
}
```

i.e. In the form `rgb(#fff)`. This makes them not work in the browser.

These are defined in the scss using variables and the `unquote` scss function like so

`$button-fab-color-alt: unquote("rgb(#{$color-accent})") !default;`

However when I inspect the compiled css that comes with MDL this isn't the case. The colors are being defined like `color: rgb(255,255,255)`.

It looks like something in the MDL build changes color hex's to rgb values... but can't work out where or how.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide the exact code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I'd include more if I knew where things were going wrong. The code that reproduces the problem is the second block above ie defining colours like this `unquote("rgb(#{$color-accent})")` in scss compiles to this `rgb(#fff)` not this `color: rgb(255,255,255)` like it obviously does when MDL compile their scss. I can't be much clearer than that.

Comment: What is `$color-accent` set to?  Is this a variable you've modified?  If so, what was the original value?

Comment: Yes that is a color I defined and that's the problem! MDL define all their color vars in the rgb form... not hex. Thankyou very much! I've been staring at this problem way to long to realise it's something as simple as that. Thanks again.